# Network Link Conditioner

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am trying to throttle my network on my real iPhone to simulate users with slow connections. I have turned on Developer Mode and Enabled Network Link Conditioner and no profiles are showing up.

I tried to go to the device and simulator in Xcode and throttle using the network link setting and I got the message setup failed.

I have restarted my phone multiple times, turned on/off developer mode, restarted Xcode, restarted my mac, and reset my network settings on IOS. The add profile button does nothing but make the text bigger and shrink back down. Nothing appears to be working. I am at a loss. How do I get my profiles to show up and work so I can test throttled connections on my real device?

[image]

Comment: is your phone managed by (company) MDM?

Comment: @klangfarb its my person device not managed by any organization

Answer (score 4):

I am having this same issue across multiple devices but within Xcode you can open (Window -> Devices and Simulators) and connect your device and select it and you will have the option to control network conditions from within that menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got "Setup failed." on the first device I tried this on, but another one worked.